# Is it correct to let entities call repository store methods?

Tags: domain-driven-design

For example if I have 2 aggregate roots AR1 and AR2, and AR1 updates AR2 in some way - what is the proper way of storing that change in the repository? Should AR1 call the repository store method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dislike the idea of having repositories commiting changes to the database.

In my case, the xRepository.Add(x) only attaches the entity/AR to the current unit of work.

To perform the actual commit to db, I call commit on my uow.

eg.

C#

```cs
using(var uow = UoW.Begin()
{
     var ar1Repo = new Ar1Repository(uow);
     var ar1 = ar1Repo.FindById(123); //fetch already persistent entity

     var ar1.MakeChangesToAr2();

     //both ar1 and ar2 are persistent and known by the UoW
     //so no need to add them to the repositories since they 
     //are already _in_ the repositories         

     uow.Commit();
}
```

or:

```cs
using(var uow = UoW.Begin()
{
     var ar1Repo = new Ar1Repository(uow);
     var ar2Repo = new Ar2Repository(uow);
     var ar2 = new AR2();
     var ar1 = new AR1(AR2);
     ar1.MakeChangesToAr2();

     //attach the new entities to the uow
     ar1Repo.Add(ar1);
     ar2Repo.Add(ar2);

     uow.Commit();
}
```

This way, you can commit entire batches of changes at once, instead of trying to do atomic commits per entity where you might get problems committing object graphs.

This idea is based on Jimmy Nilssons ideas in his book Applying Domain Driven Design and patterns.

Comment: Great points Roger, but I don't think this answers the main question which is whether it is ok to have an Entity call methods on the repository. I think the general consensus is "no, do not allow entities to call repository methods" since it is an indirect break of Persistence Ignorance and makes testing more difficult.

Answer (score -1):

I would have a method in AR2 named Save().  This method would instantiate the repository to save itself.  AR1 could then call the Save() method on AR2 once it has made the change.

Comment: Is this really the way to go? It does not sound like its part of the domain. And entities should not know that they are being persisted?

Comment: That would make it more like Active Record than true DDD